# KeyAttestation in Android Nougat API 24

Tags: android, security, tee

I read about the new key attestation API in Android N and wanted to test it but I'm missing some classes.

The key attestation is described here: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/key-attestation.html

In the first code snipped a Attestation class is used which can't be found with the targetAPI set to API 24.

```
Attestation hardwareKeyAttestation = new Attestation(attestationCert);
```

Do I miss here anything? Do I need proprietary libraries?

Comment: Seems like the key attestation did not made it into the final version...

Comment: There is still an extra page describing the functionality and it's mentioned in the list of top features added in the Android N for Developers menu...

Comment: I'm also interested in more informations about the key attestation api in android. As far as i know that documentation page wasn't live few weeks ago..

Comment: They have updated the page you have link in your question. Check it out