# How to implement Android Key Attestation

Tags: android, x509certificate, android-security, android-7.0-nougat

According to the [Android 7.0 changes for developers](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#key_attestation) there should be a way to [create an attestation object](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation.html#verifying). However the Attestation class is not publicly available within the Android API. How am I supposed to implement [this code](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation.html#verifying) if the classes are not public? Did Google forget to publish something.
I'm targeting the latest Android SDK Version (24).

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/38482705/4571082